# How do I pass values between steps in an Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In the first step of my Logic App I call my API "Log On" endpoint passing in an Id/Password and receive a token.

How do I include that token in the header of all following requests?

Authorization: bearer TOKEN

I cannot work out how to read the response from the Log On and extract the token and then pass it in the header of all following calls.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do it is as follows.
1) Let us say your successful response from the log on HTTP action looks like below (sample taken from [Authorize access to Azure Active Directory web applications using the OAuth 2.0 code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code))

```html
{
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1THdqcHdBSk9NOW4tQSJ9.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.JZw8jC0gptZxVC-7l5sFkdnJgP3_tRjeQEPgUn28XctVe3QqmheLZw7QVZDPCyGycDWBaqy7FLpSekET_BftDkewRhyHk9FW_KeEz0ch2c3i08NGNDbr6XYGVayNuSesYk5Aw_p3ICRlUV1bqEwk-Jkzs9EEkQg4hbefqJS6yS1HoV_2EsEhpd_wCQpxK89WPs3hLYZETRJtG5kvCCEOvSHXmDE6eTHGTnEgsIk--UlPe275Dvou4gEAwLofhLDQbMSjnlV5VLsjimNBVcSRFShoxmQwBJR_b2011Y5IuD6St5zPnzruBbZYkGNurQK63TJPWmRd3mbJsGM0mf3CUQ",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "expires_on": "1388444763",
  "resource": "https://service.contoso.com/",
  "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4rTfgV29ghDOHRc2B-C_hHeJaJICqjZ3mY2b_YNqmf9SoAylD1PycGCB90xzZeEDg6oBzOIPfYsbDWNf621pKo2Q3GGTHYlmNfwoc-OlrxK69hkha2CF12azM_NYhgO668yfcUl4VBbiSHZyd1NVZG5QTIOcbObu3qnLutbpadZGAxqjIbMkQ2bQS09fTrjMBtDE3D6kSMIodpCecoANon9b0LATkpitimVCrl-NyfN3oyG4ZCWu18M9-vEou4Sq-1oMDzExgAf61noxzkNiaTecM-Ve5cq6wHqYQjfV9DOz4lbceuYCAA",
  "scope": "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read",
  "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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."
}
```

2) You add a parse json action after the HTTP call to the log on url. use the sample response from your logon api response.
3) The parse JSON now gives you access to individual fields in the response
Refer a sample work flow which calls the Microsoft AAD endpoint
- The first black box shows you the place where you feed the response from the call to the LogOn API
- The second black box is where you click and provide a sample response from the API so that the engine can generate the schema to parse the response against
- Third box shows you how you can just pass the value of access_token received (as per the sample response added above)

[image: Sample Logic App Flow]

[image: JSON fileds available after parsing the response]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the token as the value of a variable and use it through your workflow.

[image]

Useful links:

https://toonvanhoutte.wordpress.com/2017/09/01/enrich-http-headers-in-logic-apps/

[Azure Logic Apps: Extract HTTP Header Key value into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656120/azure-logic-apps-extract-http-header-key-value-into-a-variable)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values